# Divi builder and Contact form 7 Conflict

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a custom Wordpress theme with using Divi builder but when I installed the Contact form 7 I See my Home page is blank and on a console I see this error form Divi builder JS.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
    at divi-builder.min.js?ver=2.19.9:95
    at divi-builder.min.js?ver=2.19.9:95
    at divi-builder.min.js?ver=2.19.9:95
    at divi-builder.min.js?ver=2.19.9:95
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Any Luck!

Thanks

Comment: its not contact form 7 issue. Please read properly

Comment: yes but it conflict with Divi builder when i disable the plugin home page is working fine

Comment: working with which wordpress version and divi version ?

Comment: is there MailPoet 3?

Comment: Wordpress version 5.0.3 and divi builder is 2.19.9 and no mailpoet plugin installed

Comment: get an issue clear its jquery mobile issue

Comment: so now what is the solutiion

Comment: open file divi-builder/js/divi-builder.min.js and navigate to 95 line

Answer (score 1):

Issue with Jquery version. Go to theme folder and add code in functions.php :

```
function replace_core_jquery_version() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js", array(), '3.1.1' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-migrate', "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js", array(), '3.0.0' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'replace_core_jquery_version' );
```

Comment: i have tried this but still error comes when active the contact form 7

Comment: i fix this it was jquery which is already loaded by Divi and i have also loaded manually so now its working

Comment: I am getting the same problem, can you please help me so that I can find which two versions are loaded and how to stop one of them from loading

Comment: Just remove all version reenqueue it

Answer (score -1):

If you want a simple contact form then Divi has its own Contact Form module so you can create a new contact form without any conflict, even you can import the [free Divi layouts](https://www.divisiteexamples.com/free-layouts/) with contact form niche.